# Change keyboard Ubuntu 16.04 VM on Macbook air

Tags: virtual-machine, ubuntu-16.04

I have just installed Ubuntu 16.04, VM on macbook Air and I'd need to set the keyboard to Italian layout since now it's English US. I tried with System Settings and changed Text Entry, but any of the Italian configurations there is ok for my one years old macbook air.

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: better to ask this question on https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Thanks, it's a good idea.